# SSRS Cube report drillthrough parameters

Tags: reporting-services

Using SSRS v3.0  (SQLServer 2008 R2 and correspsonding BIDS version)
I have successfully implemented a drillthrough report on cube data.  The child report will use the parent report parameters as selected by the user when user clicks on a report cell.  But what I really want is the selected cell parameters to be passed to the child report, not the parent report parameters used to create the report.  Example: for parent report, user selects Year, Quarter and Category.  Report displays a cross tab, expandable as drilldown to a low-level cell.  Currently when the cell is clicked, the child report uses the broad params of the parent (as set up in the cell-textbox Action "go to report").  I want the cell Action to use parameters derived from only that particular cell: it's year, month, category, etc.

I have searched for but cannot find a report property that accesses cell parameters.  (BTW, in the Cube browser, the Action there automagically does this for me and I get correct subreport data for only the cell selected).

Answer (score 0):

In the drillthrough action on the parent report, you use the field names for the items the user is clicking (like Fields!Year.Value, Fields!Quarter.Value, etc.) and assign those to the child report parameters in the same way that you can pass parent parameters to the child parameters. When the user clicks a cell to launch the child report, the current scope for year, quarter, etc. gets passed to the child report as parameters.